# convert long [] data to ArrayList<BigInteger>

Tags: java

I have

`long [] data` and i need to convert it to `ArrayList<BigInteger>`

Is there an easy way to do this? or i have to write a foreach loop and get the BigInteger value of long and add to the list?

Any  shortcut?

Comment: No shortcut. You'll have to implement these 3 lines of code yourself.

Comment: 3 lines is more than 1 line. and that s lotta code.

Comment: That you will have to try by yourself, if there comes any problem in that then only we can help.

Comment: why is the downvote. this is a legitimate question for a lazy person.

Comment: @DarthVader, exactly, SO isn't a site for lazy people.

Comment: Closures in Java 8 might bring a one line solution to your problem but before that...

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko every developer is lazy.

Comment: You could write yourself a static convenience method in a helper library so that you can do this with a line of code later on, but if you're only doing it once then no point in the overhead

Comment: The effort required to ask the question exceeds the effort required to write the for-loop.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I know but the information you require with the answer is more valuable than the effort taking the time to write the questions. IMO.

Comment: @DarthVader I require nothing. I'm just observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jb-nizet (JB Nizet) said, there are no shortcuts to this task.
And here is the 3 lines of code to "convert" a long[] in a List

```
long[] data = { 1l, 3l, 5l, 7l, 13l, 17l};
// 3 lines to convert long[] in a List<BigInteger>
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>(data.length); // optmized as suggested
for(long num : data)
    list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(num));
```

Comment: Could be optimized with `new ArrayList<BigInteger>(data.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing in the standard Java library that would perform this exact function.